# Solution for the Invalid URL non-numeric port error?

Tags: python

I am trying to use a cryptcurrency API to get some information from a remote server in python. The example from the API how to do it is here: https://developers.cryptoapis.io/technical-documentation/blockchain-data/unified-endpoints/get-transaction-details-by-transaction-id

But when I try to run it I get an exception

*Exception has occurred: InvalidURL
nonnumeric port: '//rest.cryptoapis.io/v2'*

I am not sure what is wrong here (new to Python). Can someone please point out? I thought at least the formal example from the API provider must work?

My code is:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("https://rest.cryptoapis.io/v2")
headers = {
  'Content-Type': "application/json",
  'X-API-Key': "API key provided by the software provider"
}
conn.request("GET", "blockchain-data,bitcoin,testnet,transactions,4b66461bf88b61e1e4326356534c135129defb504c7acb2fd6c92697d79eb250", headers=headers )

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Where is YOUR code?

Comment: I copied the same as provided in the example (python) of that web page link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you misunderstood the documentation. You may find this helpful:-

```
import requests
import json

APIKEY = 'YourAPIKeyGoesHere' # <-----
BASE = 'https://rest.cryptoapis.io/v2'
BLOCKCHAIN = 'bitcoin'
NETWORK = 'testnet'
TID = '4b66461bf88b61e1e4326356534c135129defb504c7acb2fd6c92697d79eb250'
with requests.Session() as session:
    h = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'X-API-KEY': APIKEY}
    r = session.get(
        f'{BASE}/blockchain-data/{BLOCKCHAIN}/{NETWORK}/transactions/{TID}', headers=h)
    r.raise_for_status()
    print(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot DarkKnight. It seems to work! :) But I am not sure what is wrong with the code I have. That is the code from official site and seems fine too. Yours is an alternative implementation but I am still curious for the official one?